# Python CSV Sniffer detecting double-quoted text-qualifiers

Tags: python, csv, sniffer

I'm writing a Python script to parse csv files in a directory and output SQL CREATE TABLE statements for each file it finds.

```
directory = os.fsencode(".")
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)

    if filename.endswith(".csv"): 
        f = open(filename, 'r', encoding="iso-8859-1")
        dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(f.read(4096))
        f.seek(0)
        reader = csv.reader(f, dialect)
```

A simple example of my data looks like this:

```
ID|Text1|Text2|Year

"123"|"more data"|"A pipe symbol | typed by an end user"|"2014"
```

The double-quotes are included to prevent the user-typed pipe from being interpreted as a delimiter.

Here is what sniffer is returning as a dialect on my actual data:

```
['delimiter', 'doublequote', 'escapechar', 'lineterminator', 'quotechar', 'quoting', 'skipinitialspace']

['|', False, None, '\r\n', '"', 0, False]
```

I'm trying to process the values in the data using code adapted from this:
https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/python-create-table

All columns are returning varchar and all but the first and last columns are returning varchar(0).

I'm thinking this is because Sniffer is not returning the correct value for 'doublequote'.

Comment: Note that the `doublequote` options has **nothing** to do with `"`. There are two different ways to do quoting of characters in CSV. The standard mandates that to include a literal `"` inside a text field you need to *double* it (hence `doublequote`). So if a column has a value `this " is a double quote` then you should write it as `"this "" is a double quote"`. Python implementation also supports the "backslash" style escaping. In which case you'd write `"this \" is a double quote`. So `doublequote = False` means that python thinks you want to use `\"` instead of `""` to escape a quote.

Comment: Why do you need a sniffer here when you already know the format upfront? Just set a delimiter to your reader (i.e. `reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="|")`) and it will do the rest _automagically_ given that double quotes are the default string/field escape characters for the reader.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta That makes great sense. Thanks for the clarification.  Our typical (time-consuming) process is to import to SQL via SSMS, specify " as the Text-Qualifier, import all as varchar(255), then set the correct data types post import. I'm trying to learn Python and thought this would be a good project. My goal is to have a script that I can point at a directory, give it an extension to loo for, and output create table statements.  A lofty goal for sure.

Comment: @zwer I guess the goal is to be incredibly lazy and just define a directory and file extension and make it do my bidding.  But mostly it's a learning opportunity.

Comment: I don't know whether I was clear. Your assumption that the problem is the `doublequote` setting is false. The dialect you side is inferred correctly parses the sample line you provided. If that is not the case there could be different issues: 1) maybe the file contents are not what you expected (like there are missing values, so what you see is what is in the file even though you expected a different result) 2) maybe the format of the file is not described by the sample line you provided. Without the input file we cannot really say which is it. IMHO, right now your question cannot be answered.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a longer sample and explain what the expected output for it should be.

Comment: I think I should create a new question.  The initial question was poorly asked.  I believe @GiacomoAlzetta answered my question in pointing out what "doublequote" actually represents.  Based on that response it appears Sniffer is actually working correctly and there is a problem elsewhere in my code.

Comment: @MartinEvans after gaining new information from Giacomo Alzetta my question has changed significantly.  What would be the best way to handle this for future stackoverflow readers.  Should I completely edit this question or should I start a new one?

Comment: As mentioned, for the sample you gave everything is working fine. You need to work out what is going wrong. Write a test script that just outputs the decoded header row from each file found (and maybe the first row). You could then easily see which files are causing problems.